# How can we provide the output of a Linear layer to a Conv2D in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, autoencoder, torchvision

I am building an Autoencoder where I need to encode an image into a latent representation of length 100. I am using the following architecture for my model.

```
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels = 3, out_channels = 32, kernel_size=3)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32,out_channels=64,kernel_size=3,stride=2)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64,out_channels=128,kernel_size=3,stride=2)

        self.linear = nn.Linear(in_features=128*30*30,out_features=100)

        self.conv1_transpose = nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=128,out_channels=64,kernel_size=3,stride=2,output_padding=1)
        self.conv2_transpose = nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=64,out_channels=32,kernel_size=3,stride=2,output_padding=1)
        self.conv3_transpose = nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=32,out_channels=3,kernel_size=3,stride=1)
```

Is there any way I could give my `Linear` layer's output to a `Conv2D` or a `ConvTranspose2D` layer so that I can reconstruct my image? The output is restored if I remove the `Linear` layer. I want to know how I can reconstruct my image keeping the `Linear` layer

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use another linear layer:

```
self.linear2 = nn.Linear(in_features=100, out_features=128*30*30)
```

And then reshape the output into a 3D volume and pass it into your de-convolution layers.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can't believe that idea did not cross my mind

Comment: However, I am still getting an error while training despite the output shapes having the desired output. `RuntimeError: shape '[8, 115200]' is invalid for input of size 2113536`. Could you please have a look at code here -
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1VCJu2YI7wGbLdTwjRourgtgzMfKX-vUy

Comment: That's weird, I tried out your code and it returned the correct dims after the 1st de-convolution layer. I got a tensor with `torch.Size([n=2, 64, 62, 62])`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I actually forgot to actually apply my transforms in my DataLoader despite having defined them It works perfectly now.